# Jquery fileupload remove selected file on error

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery fileupload plugin to upload file. My problem is that when ever due to some error i return error with JSON I want the previously selected file to be deleted for which I have used:

```
$('#fileUpload').fileupload("destroy");
```

Here is what my code looks like

```
$('#fileUpload').fileupload({
            autoUpload: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            change: function (e, data) {
                /******************************* Applying file validations ********************************************/
                var allowedExtensions = "";
                @if (Model.DocumentType.ToLower() == "cr")
                {
                    @:allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "xlsm", "pdf", "txt", "rtf", "msg", "csv", "ppt", "pptx", "tar", "xml", "7zip", "zip", "zipx", "bmp", "tif", "tiff"];                        
                }
                else
                {
                    @:allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'];                        
                }
                var value = data.files[0].name,
                file = value.toLowerCase(),
                extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                if ($.inArray(extension, allowedExtensions) == -1) {
                    $("#invoiceUploadForm").find('#fileUpload').val('');
                    data.files = [];
                    @if (Model.DocumentType.ToLower() == "cr")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @:kendoAlert('Please select only files of type JP(E)G, PDF, DOC(X) or XLS(X)');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (UploadedFileNameValidation(value)) {

                        $("#invoiceUploadForm").find('#fileUploadLink').addClass('disabled').text('File Selected...');
                    }
                    else {
                        kendoAlert("File name contains special character. Please remove special characters.");
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var fileName = '';
                if (data.files != undefined && data.files.length > 0) {
                    fileName = data.files[0].name;
                }

                $('#uploadedFileName').val(fileName); 
            },
            add: function (e, data) {
                if (UploadedFileNameValidation(data.originalFiles[0].name)) {
                    $("#invoiceUploadForm").find('#invoiceCreateBtn').click(function () {

                        if (validator.validate() && $('#ContentId').val() == 0) {
                            if ($('#InvoiceDate').length) {


                                if (validateDate) {
                                    $(".k-tooltip").hide();
                                    if (new Date(tmpinvoiceDate) > new Date()) {
                                        ExecuteMethodAfterOkClick('some message', innerUpdateFunc);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        innerUpdateFunc();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    $(".k-tooltip").show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                innerUpdateFunc();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $("#invoiceUploadForm").find('#invoiceSubmitBtn,#crpcSubmitBtn').click(function () {

                        if (validator.validate() && $('#ContentId').val() == 0) {


                                if (new Date(tmpinvoiceDate) > new Date()) {

                                }
                                else {
                                    innerUpdateFunc();
                                }
                            } else {
                                innerUpdateFunc();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    function innerUpdateFunc() {
                        kendo.ui.progress($("body"), true);
                        var values = $("#invoiceUploadForm").serializeArray();


                        data.formData = values;
                        data.submit();
                    }
                }
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                //kendo.ui.progress($("body"), false);
                var result = data.result;
                if (result.saved) {


                    if (shouldSubmitInvoice) {
                        //kendoAlert(result.Msg, 'Success!', function () {
                        //    SubmitInvoice(result);
                        //});
                        SubmitInvoice(result);
                    }
                    else {
                        PostSuccessActions(result);
                        @*kendoAlert(result.Msg, 'Success!', function () {

                        });*@

                    }
                }
                else {
                    kendoAlert(result);
                    $("#invoiceUploadForm").find('#fileUploadLink').removeClass('disabled').text('Upload');
                    $("input#fileUpload").prop("disabled", false);
                   // I have tried multiple solutions here but none of them worked
                    $('#fileUpload').fileupload("destroy");//not working
                    $('#fileUpload').val(""); //not worked
                    $('#fileUpload').files=null;//not worked
                    $('#fileUpload').replaceWith($('#fileUpload').clone(true));//not worked
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I remove the previous image selected from the plugin data and select a new one?

Comment: your code says you forgot to put $ with ('#fileUpload').fileupload("destroy") can you recheck it?

Comment: That is typo mistake here because I re write these lines which I tried. it still don't work